# Eclipse CDT Custom Makefile

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I have a C project and I'm trying to use my own makefile. In C/C++ Build Settings I unchecked "use default build command" and I also changed `make` to `make -f ${ProjDriPath}/GNUmakefile`

The make file is `GNUmakefile`. I get the following message:

> make: *** No rule to make target `/GNUmakefile'.  Stop.

The command was originally "make" and the checkbox was checked, but when I went to build in Eclipse, I got an error message about more than one main function.  I have several source files in the project that are each compiled separately.   So that's why I tried changing the Eclipse settings.  The "make" command works from the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I changed "make" to "make -f ${ProjDriPath}/GNUmakefile"
>
> I get the following message "make: * No rule to make target `/GNUmakefile'. Stop. "

I strongly suspect that you

- haven't set the environment variable `ProjDirPath`, or
- have copy-pasted the `make` command above and have the typo `ProjDriPath` only in that command, but not in the environment variable.

With the environment variable not set, it expands to an empty string, and make searches for `/GNUmakefile`, which of course doesn't exist in the root directory. Then `make` has no rule to create it, and reports that message.

Comment: You were right.  I changed the command to: make -C ${workspace_loc:/pset1/} -f GNUmakefile.  I couldn't get it to work having just the makefile or the path with the makefile.  When I split it up like this it worked.  As I understand it "-C" isn't standard.